# Excel, VBA: How to scrape certain data from multiple html websites belonging to the same domain

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

Hope the title makes any sense. My problem at this moment is rather specific, but I think there's a solution that is also relevant to others using other domains.

I have an excel-document with a list of 1000+ URLs in the B-column (starting from B1). What I would want to accomplish through VBA is to open each of these URLs (through some kind of loop) and copy a certain line of text from the web page into the C-cell. In my document, the links all refer to different beers I've tasted and their corresponding pages on ratebeer.com. What I would want the code to do is to paste the beer style as mentioned on the site in the C-cell beside the URL (as an example, for the URL https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/3-fonteinen-doesjel/77584/ , I would want the text "Lambic Style - Gueuze" to appear in my excel file).

Sorry if there are similar answers out there that I've missed, I'm just not very experienced with VBA so it's difficult to know what exact words to search for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be done by combining Beautifulsoup and openpyxl in Python.

Do all of the links have the same format as the example?

Comment: Yes, it's only the last two parts that change

Comment: I created a program in python and it worked for the example page, but I'm not sure if it will work for the other pages. Could you give me a few more examples?

Comment: https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/3-fonteinen-oude-geuze-golden-blend/167701/
https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/3-fonteinen-zwetbe/134551/ https://www.ratebeer.com/beer/alesmith-speedway-stout/14232/

Comment: It worked for these thrree pages. I uploaded the python code and excel file which has the same format as yours on my github account : https://github.com/Haruty/stackoverflow. Please download them and check how it works.

Comment: You're welcome! Is there anything you don't understand in my code?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

```
Sub Sample()


Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = True

Dim wsSheet As Worksheet, Rows As Long, links As Variant, IE As Object, link As Variant
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set wsSheet = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")

Set IE = New InternetExplorer

Rows = wsSheet.Cells(wsSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
links = wsSheet.Range("A1:A" & Rows)

With IE
    .Visible = True
    For Each link In links
        .navigate (link)
        While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
        wsSheet.Range("B" & Rows).Value = .Document.body.innerText
    Next link
End With

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Simply modify it to suit your specific needs.